# How is the sum of squares of residuals divided by variance has a chi-square distribution with n-2 degrees of freedom?

Tags: statistics, regression

I came across this while reading the Linear Regression chapter in Sheldon Ross's Book:

[image]

So my doubt is that How can I prove that it is a chi-square distribution with degree n-2. I looked up a bit but couldn't find the proof on the internet.Thanks:)